# Enable TextBox when combobox's specific item is selected in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am using MVVM conceot to develop my project.
I have view with combobox and textbox, i want the textbox enabled only when combobox's spesific item is selected.Combobox's item source is binded to a string list and all i want to do is when the 4th element of list which is "Other" is selected  enabling the textbox and disabled otherwise.
In the view, i have

```
      <ComboBox x:Name="department_Combobox"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 

    ItemsSource=" {Binding Path= DepartmentList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Department}"

    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Height="25" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Row="17" 

     Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"  >

     </ComboBox>

     <TextBox x:Name="department_Name_TextBox"  Text="{Binding  

   Path=Department,Mode=TwoWay}"    Grid.Row="17"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2"

   Width="201" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"     />
```

how can i make enable textbox when the 4th list of Departmentlist is selected only and disable when the other elements are selected?
Thanks.

Comment: looks like this is better to use Trigger than Binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As King King stated, you should use a Trigger for this. I'd add a property "SelectedDepartment" to bind your comboboxes SelectedItem too. Otherwise, as you type in the TextBox and it updates Department, it will no longer meet the conditions of the Trigger and will disable the textbox. Change your logic elsewhere to return the SelectedDepartment value unless that is "Other" then use Department value.

I added IsEnabled defaulting to False and a Trigger bound to the SelectedDepartment that will enable the TextBox when the value is "Other".

```
<TextBox x:Name="department_Name_TextBox" 
         Text="{Binding Path=Department, Mode=TwoWay}"
         Grid.Row="17"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         Grid.Column="2"
         Width="201"
         Height="24"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         HorizontalAlignment="Right">
   <TextBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
         <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                 Value="False" />
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedDepartment}"
                         Value="Other">
               <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                       Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

**EDIT:** To clear out the TextBox value when the ComboBox switches off of "Other", I'd add an OnSelectedDepartmentChanged method to handle this.

```
private string _SelectedDepartment;
public string SelectedDepartment
{
   get { return _SelectedDepartment; }
   set
   {
      if (value == _SelectedDepartment)
         return;

      _SelectedDepartment = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDepartment");
      OnSelectedDepartmentChanged();
   }
}

private void OnSelectedDepartmentChanged()
{
    if (!SelectedDepartment.Equals("Other"))
       Department = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Normally I would recommend to use a trigger too. One question: what is about testability? One other solution is to bind your selected item of the combo box and make a property that checks that bound property and is used to show or hide the textbox. I dont know if its better or not.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works and i have another question which is how to clean textbox's text when Other is unselected?i mean, while other elements of list are selected, how textbox remains empty

Comment: @Andre We have an Automated UI Test Engineer that writes coded UI tests to test things like this. You certainly could use your method of handling this, I just personally don't like having SelectedDepartment raise property changed event for other properties unless I need to (usually use this for calculated properties).